# pyspark drop "reverse-duplicates" (rows with the same values but in reversed order

Tags: python, pyspark, duplicates

How can I drop rows in a Pysaprk DataFrame that have the same values in columns COLA and COLB, but in reverse order, without regard to which pair will be left?

In pandas, I would make a column with a list of unique entries and would drop by it. Using python lists in pyspark makes it much less efficient, therefore I am looking for another solution.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post what you expect to see in the output, so the question becomes more clear?